# Show that $f(z) = \frac{\sin(\pi/z)}{z + 2}$ , is nowhere analytic for $|z| < a$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

can someone help me with this? It doesn't ask for the whole plane yet it asks for a specific circle so i am not sure how to do.
    Show that $f(z) = \frac{\sin(\pi/z)}{z + 2}$ ,
is nowhere analytic for $|z| < a$, where $a$ is a some positive number.

Also sorry about not writing the equation in formatted form.

Comment: Again this question? It is false: the function $\;f(z)=\cfrac{\sin\frac\pi z}{z+2}\;$ is analytic EVERYWHERE but at $\;z=-2,0\;$ ...

Comment: Yeah that's what i thought, but this was my midterm question.

Comment: Then either your teacher wanted you to tell that, or he made a mistake...or **you** people have a very particular of "nowhere analytic" ...

Comment: There is an essential singularity at $z_0=0$ , and a pole of order 1 at $z_1=-2$ .

Comment: In order to determine if it has essential (or removable etc.) singularity, what kind of method should i use? Unfortunately i cannot turn it into laurent series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given function is analytic everywhere except at $0$ and $-2$. There is no $a>0$ such that $f$ is nowhere analytic on $|z|<a$.

Indeed, if $f(z)$ is not the constant zero function and is analytic on some open connected set $\Omega$, then $1/f(z)$ is analytic on $\Omega\setminus Z(f)$, where $Z(f)=\{z\in\Omega:f(z)=0\}$. Note that the set $Z(f)$ consists of isolated points (if it has a limit point, the function would be identically zero).

Products of analytic functions are analytic. The same for compositions, provided the resulting function is defined over an open set (this could be refined, but it is sufficient for our purposes): the chain rule is your friend here.

The point $-2$ is a pole of order one for your function, because
$$
(z+2)f(z)=\sin\frac{\pi}{z}
$$
has a removable singularity at $-2$ (being the restriction of an analytic function in a neighborhood of $-2$).

Since $1/(z+2)$ is analytic in a neighborhood of $0$, the singularity type of $f$ at $0$ is the same as for
$$
g(z)=\sin\frac{\pi}{z}
$$
Note that there is no limit of $|g(z)|$ as $z\to 0$: just compute the limit on suitable sequences converging to $0$. Therefore $0$ is an essential singularity.